# Java: Protected or Public, do not matter

Tags: java

Why when I put "//" before

```
extends Point
```

nothing changes in the result?

```
public class lab11info
{
    public class Point
    {
        private float x;
        private float y;
        protected float getX(){
            return x;   
        }
        protected float getY(){
            return y;   
        }
        protected void setX(float newX){
            x = newX;   
        }
        protected void setY(float newY){
            y = newY;   
        }
    }
    public class Points extends Point
    {
        private Point[] points;
        public Points(int numberOfPoints)
        {
            this.points = new Point[numberOfPoints];
        }
        public void pointSetX(int index, float x)
        { 
            if(points[index]==null)
            points[index] = new Point();
            points[index].setX(x);
        }
        public void pointSetY(int index, float y)
        { 
            if(points[index]==null)
            points[index] = new Point();
            points[index].setY(y);
        }
        public float pointGetX(int index)
        { 
            if(points[index]!=null)
            return points[index].getX();
            else
            return 0f;
        }
        public float pointGetY(int index)
        { 
            if(points[index]!=null)
            return points[index].getY();
            else
            return 0f;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        lab11info Main = new lab11info();
        Points points = Main.new Points(5);
        points.pointSetX(1,1.9099f);
        System.out.println(points.pointGetX(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect anything to change?

Comment: Because `class`es can be not extending `Point`.

Comment: You're changing whether the class extends `Point` or doesn't. That has *nothing* to do with `public` or `protected` as per your title, and it makes no difference whether or not `Points` extends `Point` when you're not using any of the members of `Point`. Try using (in `main`) `points.setX(10f);`. That will *only* work when `Points` extends `Point`.

Comment: If you mean "how come Points can call `protected` methods of Point even when it isn't a subclass", it's because `protected` in Java allows access by any class in the same package, as well as by subclasses.

Answer (score 4):

What you are observing has nothing to do with whether fields and methods are `public` or `protected`.

Your `Points` class doesn't make any use of the methods and fields it inherits.  Neither does the `main` method.  That's why nothing changes when you remove the `extends`.

But the real problem here is that what your object modelling (i.e. `Points extends Point`) is "saying" doesn't make much sense.

- A `Points` object encapsulates a "sort of" list of `Point` instances, with methods for accessing and updating the respective Points' X and Y values.
- But then you say that a `Points` object *is-a* `Point`; i.e. the `Points` object has an additional `X` and `Y` coordinate ... independent of the coordinates of the `Point` components of the `Points` object.

The idea that a collection of points should have additional X,Y coordinates is ... hard to fathom ... and I'm pretty sure that this is not what you *intended* to express in your modelling.

---

<sup>The only possible relevance of `public` versus `protected` in this example is that code in an unrelated class would not be able to call the `protected` methods of `Point` that are inherited by `Points`.  But that is not relevant to your `main` method.  Since the `main` method is a method of `Points`, it *could* legally call those methods.</sup>